# How to enable spring security logging using log4j in an spring(not boot) project?

Tags: spring, logging, spring-security, log4j2, spring-oauth2

I am trying to enable logging for spring security packages but it's just not working, while the logger is working fine for other packages.

**log4j.properties:**

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG, console
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security.oauth2=TRACE, console

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**SecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment messageProperty;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/","/deletesession").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/myapp")
        .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
        .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService())
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/logincheck",true);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(
            clientRegistrationRepository());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {


        ClientRegistration myClient =
                CefproOAuth2Provider.MYAPP.getBuilder("myapp")
                        .clientId(messageProperty.getProperty("AUTH_CLIENT_ID"))
                        .clientSecret(messageProperty.getProperty("AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET"))
                        .build();
        
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(myClient);
    }

}
```

**log4j dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have followed lots of article but none of them worked in my scenario.I am not able to diagnose the real issue here.

Comment: What are your log related dependencies.

Comment: Are you really using Log4j or are you using Log4j2?

Comment: I am using Log4j2. Please check my updated question for dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The common answer is Apache Commons Logging https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

Specifically from: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html#Obtaining_a_Log_Object

```
public class YourClass
{
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass();
```